# SFTP Tunnel using IP tables

Tags: iptables

I need to create an IP tables configuration to access an SFTP server in from my local computer which via EC2 machine whose IP is whitelisted by SFTP server.

So the request will look like localhost -> EC2 Tunnel Machine -> Original SFTP Server

So In my local Filezilla, I should be able to access sftp using the command `sftp ec2-machine-ip 19000` ( where 19000 is the port through which I am trying to access the SFTP via EC2. This EC2 machine should connect to `original-sftp-host:22` and list the files in that stfp machine

I am bothered about the IP table configuration only.

I tried the below code which didn't workout

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 19000 -j DNAT --to-destination sftp-machine-ip:22
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -d localIP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: in commands you enter `--dport 1900`, in text you mention `19000`.

Comment: The `FORWARD` table is traversed after `PREROUTING`, so put `sftp-machine-ip` instead of `localIP`.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 19000 -j DNAT --to-destination {SFTP_SERVER_IP}:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```